Is it acceptable for new catalytic converter to have a pin hole leak at a weld?
Is it acceptable or normal for new catalytic converter to have a pin hole leak at a weld? I found the pin hole by turning out the lights, and shining a spotlight into the end of the unit, and then looking to see light peeking out. I found a pin hole of light.

On the topic of testing catalytic converters for leaks: another way to test for leaks is to plug one end with a racket ball (hold in place with a rubber bungee cord), blow air into one end with a vacuum cleaner, spray the body with soapy water, and look for bubbles.

soap bubble test can provide photo/video evidence if you feel that you might need it.

A pinhole leak on any factory-new exhaust component is a defect in workmanship that should qualify for free replacement under warranty.
You didn't mention a jurisdiction, but if this vehicle is in the USA, installing that catalytic converter would violate federal law 49 CFR 393.83(g):

No part of the exhaust system shall leak or discharge at a point
forward of or directly below the driver/sleeper compartment.

The law says "leak" and it doesn't distinguish between a pinhole leak and a major leak, but a leak is a leak. If the particular vehicle has a short cab like a pickup truck, this would not violate the law, but for any typical passenger vehicle the cat is below the driver's compartment and a pinhole leak or any leak at all is forbidden.

USA, and yes, under the driver/sleeper compartment. Such easy defects to find, are manufacturers required to test for leaks? Thanks!

@MarkPeterson I don't know of any U.S. law that requires parts manufacturers to test their products before sale, but their insurance companies probably have something to say about it. Social media criticism of defective products seems to get the attention of manufacturers these days, according to Consumer Reports.
